# Google Play Developer Console - I get "An unexpected error..." whenever I try to Edit Release

Tags: google-play-developer-api

I am trying to update my App on store. When ever I try to Edit Release, or publish an update, or even when I try to go on Store Listing section, I get this error. For almost 2 weeks I am not able to update my apk and I am loosing a lot of users because of the bugs I am not fixing. Help!

An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Firefox, that'll be work.

Or you can simply use Google Chrome in English. I think problem is about language coding.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Developer Console has been updated since July 2020, please use latest version or open it manually through this link https://play.google.com/console

Answer (score 0):

Try Firefox (as the other answerer suggested) ... this worked for me, when Chrome didn't!